# style an element using an angular filter

Tags: angularjs

I would like to style a couple of elements using a filter to decipher if it should be yellow or red.

I understand filters should not carry logic operations in them as such so am guessing a service is the first port of call before i create any filter for it.

I am leveraging data from a backend (still a bit unsure of the Backend model here, but know I can leverage certain objects to obtain the data needed for working on) I mostly need to know if i`m on the right path by using a service to control the logical outcome and then a filter to provide 'filtration' of that outcome.

BTW: sorry, im waiting for my project to checkout from SVN at mo so cannot provide a skeleton attempt. 
Will do in a bit though ..... 
Any advice before hand will be much appreciated
:) Gruffy - thanks for reading

Comment: Are you referring to view styling with filter. Better way would be to use `ng-style` or `ng-class`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the class attribute if you want, so your filter can simply return the CSS class to apply:

```
<p class="{{'foo'|myFilter}}">Foo</p>
```

[Here's a fiddle showing what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc576az/2/)